# QTabWidget tab switch shortcuts don't work under some Linux DE

Tags: linux, qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qtabwidget

I'm writing a rather complex editor with a huge number of keyboard shortcuts (or "hotkeys"), using standard Qt's way like QShortcut/QKeySequence. I have no prob with all this until the recent time.

For the QTabWidget easy tab switching i used documentation-recommended Alt- shortcuts, adding `&`-symbol to the tab's title text.
But under Windows 7/Linux + Gnome 3 this way works well, and under Linux + KDE/Unity - it doesn't.
I'm assume the problem is somethere in the X11 desktop environment shortcut handling mechanics. Maybe it handle Alt+ sequences itself and don't pass to the clients, for example.

Can i debug such situations in the clear way? Debugging the KDE code, for example, is too time-consuming :( Understand ALL Linux DEs shortcut code... the mission is completely impossible.

Or maybe i'm just using invalid way to write a really crossplatform Qt application?
Or, the third option - i'm just catched a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs due to Qt bug: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32908